# How to get count,type,date with distinct user_id in single query

Tags: php, mysql

I created a table in MySQL. It consists of data like this:

Table `user_pack`:

```
id    type     from         to         user_id   current_plan  created_ at   
  1    trail  01-01-2016  05-01-2016   1              0          01-01-2016
  2    free   06-01-2016  10-01-2016   1              0          06-01-2016
  3    main   11-01-2016  20-01-2016   1              1          11-01-2016
  4    main   21-01-2016  29-02-2016   1              1          21-01-2016
  5    trail  01-01-2016  29-02-2016   2              1          01-01-2016
  6    trail  01-01-2016  05-01-2016   3              0          01-01-2016
  7    free   06-01-2016  29-02-2016   3              1          06-01-2016
```

```
user_id= 1 =>first register for type=trail it started from = 01-01-2016  to=05-01-2016.in that time current_plan=1 after expired current_plan=0.
           =>second register for type=free it started from = 06-01-2016  to=10-01-2016 in that time current_plan=1 after expired current_plan=0.
           =>third register for type=main it started from = 11-01-2016  to=20-01-2016 in that time current_plan=1 after expired current_plan=1 only
           =>fourth register for type=main it started from = 21-01-2016  29-02-2016 and now it in activation current plan=1.
```

When I search in between two dates `01-01-2016` and `21-01-2016` with respect to `created_at` and `current` plan must be `1` and today date must be in between from and to date in table.

I want the output result in this way:

```
array0=>['trail count'=>1,'free count'=>0,'main count'=>0,'date'=>01-01-2016]
array1=>['trail count'=>0,'free count'=>1,'main count'=>0,'date'=>06-01-2016]
array2=>['trail count'=>0,'free count'=>0,'main count'=>0,'date'=>11-01-2016]
array3=>['trail count'=>0,'free count'=>0,'main count'=>1,'date'=>21-01-2016]
```

Comment: Your `created_ at` is in `varchar` so normal `between` condition will not work until you convert the date

Answer (score 1):

To be able to perform this type of query you should consider to split up your table into 3 different tables:

**pack_type:**

- id
- type

**pack_event:**

- id
- pack_type_id
- from
- to

**pack_registration:**

- id
- pack_event_id
- user_id
- current_plan
- created_at

This structure will prevent redundancy and also enables you to make sophisticated queries. It is also important to use date columns for `from`, `to` and `created_at`.

With this table structure you will be able to query all user registrations for the given time period and `current_plan=1` with the following query:

```
select 
    count(pe.id) as register_count, 
    pt.type 
from 
    pack_registration pr
    cross join pack_type pt
    left join pack_event pe on pr.pack_event_id = pe.id and pe.pack_type_id = pt.id
where 
    pr.current_plan = 1 and
    pr.user_id = 1 and
    pr.created_at between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-31'
group by
    pt.type
```